# bind() returning permission denied C

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to write a program that receive the port number as a command-line argument and start an HTTP server. I'm passing a listenfd to accept() to do this. However, I'm getting a permission denied from my open_listenfd() then a bad descriptor error from Accept().

The open_listenfd() and Accept() functions are copied from
http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/ics2/code/src/csapp.c

I'm passing port 100 to the program:

```
int open_listenfd(int port)
{
   int listenfd, optval=1;
   struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;

   /* Create a socket descriptor */
   if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
      return -1;

   /* Eliminates "Address already in use" error from bind */
   if (setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void *)&optval , sizeof(int)) < 0)
      return -1;

   /* Listenfd will be an endpoint for all requests to port on any IP address for this host */
   bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
   serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);
   if (bind(listenfd, (SA *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
      return -1;

   /* Make it a listening socket
    * ready to accept connection
    * requests */
   if (listen(listenfd, LISTENQ) < 0)
      return -1;

   return listenfd;
}

int Open_listenfd(int port)
{
   int rc;

   if ((rc = open_listenfd(port)) < 0)
      unix_error("Open_listenfd error");
   return rc;
}

int Accept(int s, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen)
{
   int rc;

   if ((rc = accept(s, addr, addrlen)) < 0)
      unix_error("Accept error");
   return rc;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int listenfd, connfd, port, clientlen;
   struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
   struct hostent *phost;
   char *phostaddr;

   port = atoi(argv[1]);

   listenfd = Open_listenfd(port);

   clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);

   connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *)&clientaddr, &clientlen);
   printf("%d\n", connfd);
   printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));

   return 0;
}
```

Another question is that if I want to the server to constantly accept() connections, read requests of the form

```
GET /path HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you run your code as sudo? You probably need super user permission to bind to 100. Or if you don't have sudo access use a higher port try 5555

Comment: Your code is poorly structured. It was actually `bind()` that got that error, not `listen()`, but the way you've coded it, it is impossible to tell. You need to call `perror()` immediately on a system call error, and with an indication of what you were doing that caused the error. The answer to your final question is a loop and probably a thread.

Comment: the first 1024 ports are 'special' and usually need super user privileges to use them.  as @SamRedway stated, use a port number above 1024.

Comment: 'unix_error()' function is not part of the available functions.  strongly suggest using 'perror()'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ports below 1024 are considered to be privileged in Linux, so you're going to need be the root user to open a socket on a ports < 1024